# python matplotlib -- regenerate graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a `python` function that generates a list with random values.

After I call this function, I call another function that plots the random values using `matplotlib`.

I want to be able to click some key on the keyboard / mouse, and have the following happen:

(1)  a new list of random values will be re-generated

(2)  the values from `(1)` will be plotted (replacing the current `matplotlib` chart)

Meaning, I want to be able to view new charts with a click of a button. How do I go about doing this in `python`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really [quite easy to do with matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/event_handling.html). The basic idea is to use

```
plt.connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

to call `onclick` whenever the user presses a button:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class Main(object):
    def clear(self):
        plt.clf()
    def redraw(self):
        self.clear()
        plt.plot(self.data)
        plt.title('100')
        plt.text(50,0.85,'100')
        plt.draw()
    def on_click(self,event):
        self.data=np.random.random(100)    
        self.redraw()        
    def run(self):
        plt.figure()
        plt.connect('button_press_event', self.on_click)
        plt.show() 

    def __init__(self):
        self.data=np.random.random(100)    

if __name__=='__main__':           
    m=Main()
    m.run()
    print(m.data)
```

Comment: thank you. I will give it a try! Can you also suggest how to write text (say, the number 100) at the top middle part of the chart?

Comment: @user3262424: Yes; you could use `plt.title` to place a string at the top middle part of the graph (outside the plot axes). Or, you could use `plt.text` to place a string anywhere inside the plot axes. I've modified the `redraw` method to show both.

Answer (score 0):

from matplotlib.widgets import Button

real_points = plt.axes().scatter(x=xpts, y=ypts, alpha=.4, s=size, c='green', label='real data')

#Reset Button
#*rect* = [left, bottom, width, height]
reset_axis = plt.axes([0.4, 0.15, 0.1, 0.04])
button = Button(ax=reset_axis, label='Reset', color='lightblue' , hovercolor='0.975')

def reset(event):
    real_points.remove()

button.on_clicked(reset)

plt.show()